# In Lean 4 how to use an implication in a hypothesis?

Tags: lean4, beginner

I am experimenting with my own "natural numbers" (Peano), so I don't want to use Lean 4's natural number tactics (such as add_comm or cancellation). How can the following be proved? It should have an obvious proof (using only logic and equality), but I have not found relevant examples - a Cheatsheet does indicate "apply" or "specialize".

```
example (a b c x y : Peano) (h1: a = b → a + c = c + b) (h2: x = y) : x + c = c + y := by sorry
```

Comment: I’m glad you found an answer.  Please use backticks for code in the future.  It makes it easier for everyone to read.

Comment: Also please include all relevant background definitions or imports.  I guess in this particular case it doesn’t matter what `Peano` is, but that isn’t always clear.  Also the way most people help is by copy and pasting your code into Lean, so it is important to provide a complete “minimal working example”.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try to use MWE when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing that `h1` needs to be quantified, I found a proof:

```
example (x y z : Peano) (h1: ∀ a b c:Peano, a = b → a + c = c + b) (h2: x = y) : x + z = z + y := by 
  apply h1
  apply h2
```